# How to handle Transaction timeout with @TransactionTimeout

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I do have method:

```
    @TransactionTimeout(value = 1, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    @Asynchronous
    public void asyncMethod() {
        System.out.println("start running asyncMethod in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("finished running asyncMethod in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
```

As you can see I running this in Transaction and timeout is set to 1 second and inside I have 3 second sleep. So as a result of running this method I am gettin:

```
javax.transaction.RollbackException
```

But let say I would like to implement service which will print information that transaction timeout has occured to the user. How could I achieve that?

@Glains gave me some advice in comment to use Interceptor.

I have added something like that:

```
@Interceptor
public class LoggingTimeoutInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Logger interceptor");
            System.out.println("method " + ctx.getMethod().getName());
            return ctx.proceed();
        }catch (RollbackException e) {
            System.out.println("Transaction RollbackException occured");
            return null;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is writing first two sysout correctly. But is not catching any exception and I dont know why. I was trying to change `@AroundInvoke` to `@AroundTimeout` but then it is not running at all.

Comment: Writing an interceptor with a higher priority than the transaction interceptor an catch the thrown `RollbackException` would come to my mind.

Comment: @Glains Seems like good idea, but somehow I am hot able to catch RollbackException